# Bash script. Open new terminal and run command

Tags: linux, bash, mosquitto

How can I run command in new terminal from bash? 
If I run it just from one terminal, `mosquitto_sub` - blocks the script. `xterm -e` opens new terminal but my script blocks too...

```
 #!/bin/bash 
         COUNTER=0
     xterm -e mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.103 -t test
     mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.103 -t test -m "Connected"
     cd Desktop/ScreenTool/image/
         while [  $COUNTER == 0 ]; do
         tesseract c.png output
     if grep -q Click "/root/Desktop/ScreenTool/image/output.txt"; then
        mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.103 -t test -m "Rain is here"
        echo -en "\007"
     fi
             cat "/root/Desktop/ScreenTool/image/output.txt"
    sleep 3;
  done
```

Comment: in case with xterm, if I close "new terminal", script goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To execute a command without waiting for it to finish, put it in the background with `&`.

```
#!/bin/bash 
COUNTER=0
xterm -e mosquitto_sub -h 192.168.1.103 -t test &
mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.103 -t test -m "Connected"
cd Desktop/ScreenTool/image/
while [  $COUNTER == 0 ]; do
    tesseract c.png output
    if grep -q Click "/root/Desktop/ScreenTool/image/output.txt"; then
        mosquitto_pub -h 192.168.1.103 -t test -m "Rain is here"
        echo -en "\007"
    fi
    cat "/root/Desktop/ScreenTool/image/output.txt"
    sleep 3;
done
```

Comment: thnx, for help!